# Differentiated series of a power series has the same radius of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, power-series

I am trying to prove that the radius of convergence of a power series does not change after differentiating term by term. Let $\sum a_nx^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R$. Let $R_2$ be the radius of convergence of $\sum na_nx^{n-1}$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{R_2} = \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|na_n|}
$$
Let $n_k$ be a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers such that $\sqrt[n_k]{|n_ka_{n_k}|}$ converges to the limit superior. Then we have that
$$
\frac{1}{R_2} = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[n_k]{|n_ka_{n_k}|} = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[n_k]{n_k}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[n_k]{|a_{n_k}|} = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[n_k]{|a_{n_k}|}
$$
Since the limit superior of the sequence $\sqrt[n]{|na_n|}$ is a limit of a subsequence of $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$, we conclude that
$$
\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|na_n|} \leq \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}
$$

Is the reverse inequality achieved in the same way?

Comment: If the oringinal series is inside the radius of convergence then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}<1$,  Now show that if that is true then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n|a_n|} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}<1$

Comment: why $1/R_2=lim sup |na_n|^{1/n}$? instead of  $1/R_2=lim sup |(n+1)a_{n+1}|^{1/n}$ ? since $\sum na_nx^{n-1}=\sum (n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reverse inequality is easier:  Since for all $n>1$ 
$$
\sqrt[n]{|na_n|} = \sqrt[n]{n} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} > \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}
$$
that is, since the sequence $\sqrt[n]{|na_n|}$ is term-by-term greater than $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$, we immediately know that 
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|na_n|} \geq \limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}
$$